# Update value using php

Tags: php, sql

**I want to update the marks of a student in php.
All the values are fetching properly from the table.
But after changing the value it is not updating.**

---

---

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])=="")
    {   
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    }
else
    {
    $stid=intval($_GET['stid']);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $rowid=$_POST['id'];
        $ct=$_POST['ct'];
        $wt=$_POST['wt'];
        $pro=$_POST['pro'];
        $ter=$_POST['ter'];

        foreach($_POST['id'] as $count => $id)
            {
            $c=$ct[$count];
            $iid=$rowid[$count];
    
            for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++) 
                {
                $sql="update tblresult  set ct=:c,wt=:w,pro=:p,ter=:t where id=:iid ";
                $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                $query->bindParam(':c',c,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindParam(':w',w,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindParam(':p',p,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindParam(':t',t,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindParam(':iid',$iid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
                $msg="Result info updated successfully";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3IBM.png)

Comment: First, when debugging anything, never turn off error reporting, always set it to scream loudly. `error_reporting(-1)`

Comment: The  `c` in `bindParam(':c', c , PDO::PARAM_STR )` doesn't look like a variable to me. Same for `w`, `p` and `t`. Take a look at the syntax of [`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the values you're using for `bindParam` aren't correct.

`$query->bindParam(':c',c,PDO::PARAM_STR);` for example looks like it should be:

`$query->bindParam(':c', $ct, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

I would also look at being more consistent with your variable names and maybe the 'Result info updated successfully' message is possibly a little presumptuous.